# Washer causing pipes banging, is this dangerous?

Tags: plumbing

Is this dangerous? We purchased a new washer (house is around 17 years old) and when the water clearly cuts off suddenly (it's one of those fill then check then fill washers) it makes a loud noise.

Is this something to be concerned about long term? Surely this isn't an uncommon problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some washers evidently have soft close valves that reduce water hammer. But if yours does not, then you can get water hammer arrestors. [Watts mini water hammer arrestors](https://www.grainger.com/product/5DME1?cm_mmc=PPC:%20Google%20PLA&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!50916794037!!!g!82128169917!&ef_id=Wb6hZAAABW5VfXMN:20180421012300:s) There are other designs that might fit your faucets better. I wonder if there is an adjustment on your washing machine to soften the closure of the valves. We don't have any significant water hammer from our washing machines.

Comment: How dangerous do you think it would be without getting hammer arrestors?

Comment: It may damage the pipes over time. Water hammer arrestors come in various designs.